# Quake PC Game (Steam Ver.)

Tags: steam, quake, windows-98

My inquiry is; is there a command\ prompt that can be used to play my installed Quake game via Win98, while my steam account has no internet connection (completely offline)?

I had noticed I was able to startup a title from my steam games by rummaging through the directory files of my steam folders. The game I'm mentioning was Richochet Lost Worlds, in the Common Games file of my C drive.

Additional Note, this was accessed when internet hadn't run through the PC for months. I cannot even get the Steam program to allow me to access my account  for offline purposes. Any help is appreciated. I find that it's notoriously difficult to play some older PC titles on new OS'es. But, in this case the viscious programming of steam is blocking me from playing my older title on the older Windows OS Win98 via steam.

Answer (score 6):

While windows is famous (notorious) for extreme backwards compatability, newer versions of windows have features that older ones don't.

Steam for example used to rely on IE to run (which may be why it worked before on windows 98), then it switched over to webkit, which i doubt runs on windows 98. The oldest OS officially supported is XP. Its not vicious, its common sense - they can't support *everything* - then they'd have to support things all the way back to dos

The programmes themselves arn't part of steam, so if they're an older game, they'd probably work. You're out of luck on running steam on an OS that's over a decade old, and part of a thankfully extinct branch of windows.

Sadly the solution is to get a supported OS

Answer (score 5):

If you go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common` (x86 can be removed if you don't have a 64-bit OS), you will see it, and and then can launch from the executable there.

Comment: First, x86 cannot be removed since Steam is an 32 bit application which always installs itself in the path above.

Second, Quake (up to Quake 3) are standalone games that just happen to be distributed via Steam. They don't integrate into Steamworks, so you could just as well run the game from their installation path. They won't start Steam automatically.

Comment: @Bora what? 32 bit systems don't have "(x86)" in the path. That's what Simon meant by that.

Comment: @badp You are right. I must have misunderstood that.